# How to add obfs3 bridges in Tor browser?

Tags: bridge, pluggable-transports

My OS is Microsoft Windows 7, 64-bit and I obtained the following obfs3 bridges (IP addresses and fingerprints have been altered to protect the integrity of the real bridges):

> obfs3 111.222.333.444:12345
>   *9280121gh126257961997ac2f972c7d63989af8648*
>
> obfs3 555.666.777.888:67890 *k7m21653856p587e7da0zz0e5779c0ec7b33a7a6*
>
> obfs3 999.000.111.222:65432 *4st03902010r8x0yz4ec45229bc1c093006a24a4*

When I enter custom bridges, do I have to include their respective fingerprints? that is, the 3 strings of alphanumeric characters that I have *italicized*?

Answer (score 2):

Fingerprint is not necessary here. Just type obfs3 ip:port and it will work. 
The "bridge" will be added automatically for each bridge and you might just keep it as it is.

When the format isn't correct, you'll see warning messages in Tor log.